# Import information from a different file to AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible to specify some information, such as API keys, in a file, and then somehow inject this information into the `AndroidManifest` file (maybe during the build process)?

For my particular use case, the [documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#android) for `react-native-maps` requires adding a Google Maps API key to the `AndroidManifest` file. However, I'd like to keep sensitive information out of the `AndroidManifest` file (instead, inside a file that will eventually be `gitignored` for example).

On a side note, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352629/is-there-a-way-to-keep-meta-data-in-the-android-manifest-private-to-the-package), it seems that all information inside the `AndroidManifest` is available to all packages on the same device. Is this still true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the information is only needed in the manifest, you can define [manifest placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support) in your `build.gradle` file and reference them using `${}` macro syntax in the manifest.

If the information might be needed elsewhere, consider using string resources created via `resConfig` in your `build.gradle` file.

The `build.gradle` file can pull the actual values from `gradle.properties`, a custom properties file, via some API call to a server, or whatever else you want, given sufficient Gradle/Groovy/Java coding. Typically, I have `gradle.properties` listed in `.gitignore`, and so I put this sort of thing in there, though I am not certain if that approach is common practice.

> it seems that all information inside the AndroidManifest is available to all packages on the same device. Is this still true?

"All" is a strong term, but I would say that the vast majority of information in the manifest is visible through `PackageManager`. Sometimes, it's not directly accessible (e.g., I don't recall a way to get the `<intent-filter>` list for a component), but it's still there if you find the right way to get at it.